# how do i get executable code from my source code cpp?

Tags: c++, memory, portable-executable

I watched some videos on youtube where bytes for CPP or c# code get hardcoded in an unsigned char* then get injected into memory and executed.

how can I do that with my source code? I only found a way to inject the bytes from an exe with a little bit complicated way which caused me some problems when executing.

I also found this page where they use some kind of pentesting tool to generate an executable code (bytes) that can simply get injected in memory.

https://www.ired.team/offensive-security/code-execution/using-msbuild-to-execute-shellcode-in-c

Comment: `char * code=...; goto code`. But you will have to tell your OS that the page containing `code` can execute the instructions inside.

Comment: You usually get executable code the normal way; you compile it. Alternatively, write assembly code and hand-translate to machine code like it's the 1950s.

Comment: @Quimby -- `code` is not a label; it can't be the target of a `goto` statement.

Comment: I know how to inject bytes into memory, but you can't just run code from the compiled exe you need to add headers and such. but in the example in the link, they just inject the bytes and it works just fine.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh, `goto * code;` is a GCC extension, did not know that. Inline assembly shoud still work, right?

Comment: @Quimby -- well, yes, but inline assembly is not portable C++; the `asm` keyword has no semantics. So whatever you try, you're into compiler-specific stuff.

Comment: can someone please answer me?

Comment: is that code in the example link just normal hex code. can i just convert the binary from the compiled exe to hex bytes and inject them into memory?

Comment: @molbdnilo when you compile it and show the disassembly window I don't know where the program starts or finishes so I don't know which assembly bytes to copy. and a guy just told me that it's not going to work even if i did so.

Answer (score 0):

In short: give up until you understand enough of assembly language to ejects assembly code. Blind copying of executable code won't work.

---

C++ or C# compiling produce machine code which:

1. May contain external references. A function may call other function, use global variables, etc. Even if you don't explicitly do this, the language may call its runtime. On program load time this is fixed by having all statically imported objects in executable, and loading dynamically imported modules.
2. Isn't necessarily position independent. That is it may not behave well in another memory location. It may contains absolute reference to itself that should be adjusted, or relative external references, that also should be adjusted. On program load time this is fixed by processing relocation table.
3. Actually a specific case of 1, but can be viewed separately. Executable except from code and data contains some annotations to code, most notable, exception handlers. Without exception handlers, it may not execute as expected too.

That is, arbitrary copied bytes of executable may or may not work in another location. If you try to copy entire program, most likely it will not work.

For trick like injecting code one would use assembly or machine code, not high level languages. Sorry.

---

To get machine code for your instructions generated by compiling C++ code from VS:

- During debugging - copy or drag and drop the address from Disassembly window to Memory window.
- During compilation - use [`/FAc` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fa-fa-listing-file?view=msvc-160)

Comment: i know, i guess that's what they use. the assembly machine code like "0x09 etc". but how can i get assembly code from my source code. VS has assembly debugger but it's  in "aex etc" format.

Comment: @anasouardini5, added this to my answer

Comment: thanks, but where do i set the break-ponit i set it at the int main() but it seems that a lot of things going on above that address. I thought I would search for "this program can not run in dos" and find the first address but unfortunately, you can't make a search in the address window. and where do you set the option /FAc option I'm using the VS GUI is that something that is used with a  terminal?

Comment: Read that link, it contains information on IDE option too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fa-fa-listing-file?view=msvc-160#to-set-this-compiler-option-in-the-visual-studio-development-environment

Comment: MS-DOS stub is more likely to be far away from code section of PE, rathet than near main

Comment: so this option outputs the assembly bytes for the whole project without specifying the beginning and the end addresses?

Comment: The option is for compiler, not linker, the compiler does not know the final address. Possibly you'll better off with some disassembler software instead, if you need to analyze the exact structure of a resulting executable

Comment: i used the option the GUI way like in this webpage, https://newbedev.com/how-to-view-the-assembly-behind-the-code-using-visual-c. but it says that it doesn't work with multi source files.

Comment: i only want the bytes of the assembly code. i would've copied the bytes from the memory window but i don't know where the program starts or ends. and that compiling option works only with one file.

Comment: Copying entire program is definitely useless, please read my answer.

Comment: what do you mean, I have another program that I should give the bytes of the program that I want to inject into memory, so I definitely need to inject all the bytes. then start a process using the start address and length of the bytes in the memroy.

Comment: can you please answer me?

Comment: Tried to edit again to make it more clear.

Comment: ah ok, I think that's why when I use that function that injects EXE binary works sometimes but sometimes it doesn't.
so it's necessary to fully understand assembly and how it's compiled and executed to be able to run it from memory?

Comment: so i can't just do the same as this guy did in his article (link in post).

Comment: how did he came up with these bytes though?  
`byte[] shellcode = new byte[] {0xfc,0xe8,0x82,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x60,0x89,0xe5,0x31,0xc0,0x64,0x8b,0x50,0x30,0x8b,0x52,0x0c,0x8b,0x52,0x14,0x8b,0x72,0x28,0x0f,0xb7,0x4a,0x26,0x31,0xff,0xac,0x3c, ... };`

Comment: I've used msfvenom (pentesting tool) to generate a reverse shell and copied the bytes that the tool outputs and it gave the reverse shell, which means that the code injected and run successfully.

Comment: This is written in assembly or even coded in hex manually using instructions reference

Comment: no, it's a tool that generates those bytes. so if I wrote my app in assembly and then convert the assembly into assembly bytes, I can do the same? so basically I have to write the whole code in assembly. is there an easier way without having to learn the assembly?

Comment: You will have to learn assembly for things like this.